# ASP MVC Getting image from SQLite db vs. file system

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sqlite

I have two identical images. One is saved as a .png in a folder, the other is saved as a SQLite blob in a database. I'm trying to figure out a good way to persist these images and show them in my view when needed.

I have two methods for trying to get these images into my view. The first one is reading the image files directly from the file system, converting them into a base64 string which I shove into a ViewBag. This method works fine.

The other method is trying to load the image blob directly from the database and then fetch the image from the Model in the view. This doesn't work so well.

Through a couple of breakpoints I've found out that there's a huge different between the base64 strings, depending on my method. I'm not sure why and what the difference between the SQLite image blob and the .png in my file system is, and any help would be appreciated since saving images in a folder seems like extra work, when I could just keep them in my database.

Loading from the file system:

```
    public string FirstImagePath(string slideid, int well)
    {
        var firstPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(slideid);
        byte[] firstImageByteData = File.ReadAllBytes(firstPath + "_first" + well + ".png");
        string firstImageBase64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(firstImageByteData);
        string firstImageDataUrl = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", firstImageBase64Data);

        return firstImageDataUrl;
    }
```

Loading from SQLite db:

```
    public byte[] FirstImage { get; set; }
    public string FirstBase64Image
    {
        get { return ConvertImage(FirstImage);}
    }

    public string ConvertImage(byte[] imageBytes)
    {
        byte[] imageArray = imageBytes;
        string imageBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        string imageDataString = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", imageBase64String);

        return imageDataString;
    }
```

Comment: Don't store images in databases. They don't belong there. Store the image on disk, or in a cloud storage location. Store a URI in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Both methods have their advantages and disadvantages.
If you store your images in a DB it's very easy to move the application across different platforms without having to copy a lot of images. On the other hand your DB is going to get very large over time.
Storing images on disk allows you to overwrite them easily with a copy / paste job etc. However, if you have multiple web servers, you're going to have to make this change several times.
However, this isn't the main issue that I have with your approach. The problem is that you get the images, convert them to base64 and embed them in your output. This is bad practice for many reasons. Firstly, browsers are smart enough to load in multiple resources at a time. For instance, your browser can download multiple images at a time which will drastically increase page load speed. If you have the images embeded it becomes the responsibility of the html parser to render these images which in turn slows the overall download of the html document as it's larger.

I would recommend a hybrid of the two. Upload images to your database. Create an image handler in your application that retrieves an image from the DB and attempts to save it to the file system. If it's successful return this image. The next time you try to get this image (and it's not cached on the users machine) your handler can check the file system to see if it has already been created and return it.
This method gives you the advantages of both the DB and file structure methods. If you decide you need 10 web servers, all of your images will be stored in the DB, and the file system will be automatically populated with your images as and when you need them depending on which server receives the request. I recommend using a GUID or some unique id for your images.

You could even extend this further and pass height and width parameters to the image handler that will resize the image for you before sending it back to the client.